# I am running Ubuntu WSL on Windows11 bur i am getting libs permission denied errror 52: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: Permission denied

Tags: kubuntu

/home/prankur_sharma/prankur_23/dem_gen/sw/StereoPipeline-2.7.0-2020-07-29-x86_64-Linux/bin/stereo: 52: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: Permission denied

Comment: What Ubuntu *version* are you using via WSL? In recent versions, python must be explicitly run as either `python3` or `python2` by default - the issue you are having seems to be related to the software's use of `/usr/bin/env python` - which returns nothing in that case.

Comment: Ubuntu version is 2204.2.33.0

Comment: OK so you *may* find that it works if you install the `python-is-python3` package - however I'm not sure if that's the recommended solution. Another option might be to install ASP via miniconda instead - as described in the `README.rst` file under *"Fetching pre-compiled ASP with conda"*